# Need help in understanding this multivariate random variable problem example

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables

So the purpose of this example is to show how multivariate random variables work. The example says: The dot is chosen randomly inside a triangle ((x,y) : x >0, y >0, x + y <1). What is the distribution function?

So now the example gives this picture and starts explaining it https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7uWg.jpg

it says on area 1, F(x,y) = 0, I perfectly understand that, because F(x,y) = P(X<x ,Y<y) if we were to chose dot from that area there would be no dot in triangle where there would be x > X and y > Y

on area 2 it says that F(x,y) = xy, now I don't understand this part, if we chose some dot inside that triangle we would have rectangle like it is in the picture. So the probability for another dot to land inside that rectangle would be rectangle surface / triangle surface. If I understood how random variables work correctly, that should be the answer.

on area 3 same thing it says that F(x,y) = 1−(1−x)2−(1−y)2. If I were to understand distribution function on area 2 and 3 I would easily solve for other areas. So can someone explain to me how did they got those answers for F(x,y)?

Thank you!

Edit: I understood area 2 but what about area 3, where did (1-x)^2 and (1-y)^2 came from?

Comment: anyone........??

Comment: Do you guys need more info? I would be glad to provide more detailed information about the problem

Comment: Notice the length of the triangle sides

Comment: Thank you, I understood area 2 but what about area 3, where did (1-x)^2 and (1-y)^2 came from?

Comment: You're looking for the *proportion* of the triangular area that overlaps the infinite region below and to the left of the point $(x,y).$ When $(x,y)$ is in "Region 3", the overlap (as seen in the picture) is the entire triangle except for two smaller triangular regions that have areas $(1-x)^2/2$ and $(1-y)^2/2$, so the overlap area is $1/2-(1-x)^2/2-(1-y)^2/2.$ Dividing this by the entire triangular area of $1/2$ gives $F(x,y)=1-(1-x)^2-(1-y)^2.$

Comment: Thats my answer, thank you!

Comment: Note that for $(x,y)$ in "Region 2", the same procedure gives the correct answer $F(x,y)=xy/(1/2)=2xy$ (not $xy$).

Comment: @r.e.s. yes so the correct answer is 2xy, they calculated incorrectly